# Hybrid app crashes when in landscape mode

Tags: android, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

This is funny... I've written hybrid apps earlier which don't crash when mobiles are in landscape mode.
I wrote a sample hybrid app that uses phonegap, cordova, HTML, Bootstrap, css, js to explain to a junior. I took this [link for explaining to my junior](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html).
The only change that I did was in HTML file was:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="support/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Form</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It works perfectly in portrait mode, but crashes when mobiles are put to landscape mode. Is preferences for orientation missing from androidmanifest.xml? How can I fix this?

`logcat:`

```
08-17 03:35:44.856: I/CordovaLog(12233): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-17 03:35:44.856: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
08-17 03:35:44.956: I/WebViewFactory(12233): Loading com.google.android.webview version 44.0.2403.90 (code 240309050)
08-17 03:35:45.016: I/LibraryLoader(12233): Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 5548-5550)
08-17 03:35:45.016: I/LibraryLoader(12233): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
08-17 03:35:45.026: V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider(12233): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {2a10f43e}
08-17 03:35:45.026: I/LibraryLoader(12233): Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
08-17 03:35:45.026: I/chromium(12233): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
08-17 03:35:45.036: I/BrowserStartupController(12233): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
08-17 03:35:45.036: W/art(12233): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-17 03:35:45.036: E/SysUtils(12233): ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
08-17 03:35:45.056: W/chromium(12233): [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
08-17 03:35:45.056: E/libEGL(12233): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-17 03:35:45.056: E/libEGL(12233): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-17 03:35:45.066: I/Adreno-EGL(12233): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: LNXBUILD_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.2_RB2.05.00.02.045.011+PATCH[ES]_msm8916_64_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.2_RB2.05.00.02.045.011__release_ENGG (I5c5bbe66dc)
08-17 03:35:45.066: I/Adreno-EGL(12233): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.01
08-17 03:35:45.066: I/Adreno-EGL(12233): Build Date: 02/10/15 Tue
08-17 03:35:45.066: I/Adreno-EGL(12233): Local Branch: 
08-17 03:35:45.066: I/Adreno-EGL(12233): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.2_RB2.05.00.02.045.011
08-17 03:35:45.066: I/Adreno-EGL(12233): Local Patches: 3664e49f034d0377f8c106f6aeb4ff30255be59c rb: Enable the multithreading texture upload for all A4xx chipsets
08-17 03:35:45.066: I/Adreno-EGL(12233): Reconstruct Branch: LOCAL_PATCH[
08-17 03:35:45.106: W/AudioManagerAndroid(12233): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
08-17 03:35:45.156: W/art(12233): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-17 03:35:45.176: W/AwContents(12233): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
08-17 03:35:45.176: D/EgretLoader(12233): EgretLoader(Context context)
08-17 03:35:45.196: D/EgretLoader(12233): The context is not activity
08-17 03:35:45.206: D/CordovaWebView(12233): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: Xiaomi
08-17 03:35:45.216: D/JsMessageQueue(12233): Set native->JS mode to 2
08-17 03:35:45.226: W/art(12233): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-17 03:35:45.226: W/art(12233): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-17 03:35:45.226: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CordovaActivity.init()
08-17 03:35:45.236: D/CordovaWebView(12233): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:35:45.236: D/PluginManager(12233): init()
08-17 03:35:45.236: D/CordovaWebView(12233): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-17 03:35:45.406: D/Config(12233): Unlimited access to network resources
08-17 03:35:45.406: I/CordovaLog(12233): Found start page location: index.html
08-17 03:35:45.406: I/CordovaLog(12233): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-17 03:35:45.406: D/CordovaActivity(12233): Resuming the App
08-17 03:35:45.406: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
08-17 03:35:45.406: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Render dirty regions requested: true
08-17 03:35:45.416: D/CordovaActivity(12233): Paused the application!
08-17 03:35:45.416: D/CordovaWebView(12233): Handle the pause
08-17 03:35:45.416: W/chromium(12233): [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
08-17 03:35:45.436: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(12233): Ignore this event
08-17 03:35:45.466: I/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-17 03:35:45.466: D/OpenGLRenderer(12233): Enabling debug mode 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): PartialUpdate status: Disabled
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Left Align: 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Width Align: 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Top Align: 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Height Align: 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Min ROI Width: 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Min ROI Height: 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Needs ROI Merge: 0
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Dynamic Fps: Enabled
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Min Panel fps: 45
08-17 03:35:45.496: I/qdutils(12233): Max Panel fps: 60
08-17 03:35:45.506: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(12233): Ignore this event
08-17 03:35:45.546: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(12233): Ignore this event
08-17 03:35:45.546: I/Timeline(12233): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2a6da025 time:12466089
08-17 03:35:45.566: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:35:45.596: D/CordovaLog(12233): : Line 1 : exception firing pause event from native
08-17 03:35:45.596: I/chromium(12233): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "exception firing pause event from native", source:  (1)
08-17 03:35:45.636: W/BindingManager(12233): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12233
08-17 03:35:45.776: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(12233): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.json
08-17 03:35:46.326: D/CordovaWebViewClient(12233): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:35:46.326: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:35:46.446: D/CordovaNetworkManager(12233): Connection Type: wifi
08-17 03:35:46.446: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
08-17 03:35:46.446: D/CordovaNetworkManager(12233): Connection Type: wifi
08-17 03:35:46.456: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(spinner,stop)
08-17 03:35:48.326: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(spinner,stop)
08-17 03:35:52.816: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(12233): Ignore this event
08-17 03:35:58.286: D/Config(12233): Unlimited access to network resources
08-17 03:35:58.286: I/CordovaLog(12233): Found start page location: index.html
08-17 03:35:58.286: I/CordovaLog(12233): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-17 03:35:58.286: D/CordovaActivity(12233): Resuming the App
08-17 03:35:58.286: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
08-17 03:35:58.296: I/Timeline(12233): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2a6da025 time:12478836
08-17 03:36:08.666: D/CordovaActivity(12233): Paused the application!
08-17 03:36:08.666: D/CordovaWebView(12233): Handle the pause
08-17 03:36:08.666: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CordovaActivity.onDestroy()
08-17 03:36:08.666: D/CordovaWebView(12233): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-17 03:36:08.786: D/Config(12233): Unlimited access to network resources
08-17 03:36:08.786: I/CordovaLog(12233): Found start page location: index.html
08-17 03:36:08.796: I/CordovaLog(12233): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-17 03:36:08.796: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
08-17 03:36:08.816: W/art(12233): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-17 03:36:08.826: W/AwContents(12233): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
08-17 03:36:08.826: D/EgretLoader(12233): EgretLoader(Context context)
08-17 03:36:08.826: D/EgretLoader(12233): The context is not activity
08-17 03:36:08.836: D/CordovaWebView(12233): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: Xiaomi
08-17 03:36:08.846: D/JsMessageQueue(12233): Set native->JS mode to 2
08-17 03:36:08.846: W/art(12233): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-17 03:36:08.846: W/art(12233): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
08-17 03:36:08.846: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CordovaActivity.init()
08-17 03:36:08.856: D/CordovaWebView(12233): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:36:08.856: D/PluginManager(12233): init()
08-17 03:36:08.856: D/CordovaWebView(12233): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-17 03:36:08.876: D/Config(12233): Unlimited access to network resources
08-17 03:36:08.876: I/CordovaLog(12233): Found start page location: index.html
08-17 03:36:08.876: I/CordovaLog(12233): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
08-17 03:36:08.876: D/CordovaActivity(12233): Resuming the App
08-17 03:36:08.876: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
08-17 03:36:08.916: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(12233): Ignore this event
08-17 03:36:08.956: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(12233): Ignore this event
08-17 03:36:08.956: W/BindingManager(12233): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12233
08-17 03:36:08.966: D/CordovaWebViewClient(12233): onPageFinished(about:blank)
08-17 03:36:08.966: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
08-17 03:36:08.966: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(exit,null)
08-17 03:36:09.006: D/CordovaActivity(12233): Paused the application!
08-17 03:36:09.006: D/CordovaWebView(12233): Handle the pause
08-17 03:36:09.086: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(12233): Ignore this event
08-17 03:36:09.116: D/CordovaActivity(12233): CordovaActivity.onDestroy()
08-17 03:36:09.116: D/CordovaWebView(12233): >>> loadUrlNow()
08-17 03:36:09.166: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:36:09.186: D/CordovaLog(12233): : Line 1 : exception firing pause event from native
08-17 03:36:09.196: I/chromium(12233): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "exception firing pause event from native", source:  (1)
08-17 03:36:09.196: D/CordovaLog(12233): : Line 1 : exception firing destroy event from native
08-17 03:36:09.196: I/chromium(12233): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "exception firing destroy event from native", source:  (1)
08-17 03:36:09.206: W/BindingManager(12233): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12233
08-17 03:36:09.206: D/CordovaWebViewClient(12233): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:36:09.206: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
08-17 03:36:09.216: W/BindingManager(12233): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12233
08-17 03:36:09.226: D/CordovaWebViewClient(12233): onPageFinished(about:blank)
08-17 03:36:09.226: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(onPageFinished,about:blank)
08-17 03:36:09.226: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(exit,null)
08-17 03:36:09.836: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12233): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-17 03:36:11.216: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(spinner,stop)
08-17 03:36:11.226: D/CordovaActivity(12233): onMessage(spinner,stop)
```

Comment: Can you link to a site that crashes in this way?

Comment: I didn't get you, but I followed this site:  https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html

Comment: I know, that's what you said in the question. But I tried to do that and I couldn't crash my Android tablet, so the question remains, do you have a live site that you can provide the URI of, which does crash.

Comment: Well... there is no live URL... Did you try that in landscape mode?